Cannot get my Canon M50 DSLR to be detected in OBS-Studio
I have installed Ubuntu Studio 24.04.1 LTS as I really loved how creative apps have been bundled together. I am keen to try video streaming through OBS as I already had a Canon M50 - which YouTubers have already demonstrated as working on linux.
I can use the camera & video through gphoto2 and it appears in lsusb as a device but it does not get detected in other applications such as Cheese, Entangle (although it detects it but with no picture) and OBS. OBS is the software I want to use.
I have updated the system, changed permissions, reinstalled software: gphoto2, v4l-utils, OBS without any luck.
I would hate to go back to Windows just to get this working I feel I like I am stuck.

The problem is that it isn't a video device; it's a camera that can be controlled from a computer. It doesn't natively provide a video endpoint. This may provide some useful information.

Thanks for responding and that link was helpful although I had done a lot of what was in that link. I found a workaround by buying an Elgato capture card which worked first time.
